# git clone with http.sslVerify false for a specific URL does not work

Tags: git, ssl-certificate, git-clone

My GitLab server has a self signed certificate. When I clone a repository I get

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://10.10.10.10.10/gitlab-instance-3b9321be/test.git/': Issuer certificate is invalid.
```

After running this command `git config --global http.sslVerify false` the clone completes successfully. I don't want to ignore certificates globally so I deleted my `~/.gitconfig` file and ran this command `git config --global --bool --add http.https://10.10.10.10.sslverify false`. Now my `./gitconfig` looks like this:

```
[http "https://10.10.10.10"]
    sslverify = false
```

git clone fails with the original error.

I'm running on RHEL 7.8 and my git version is 1.8.3.1. This should work based on other answers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This should work based on other answers.

(What makes you believe that?  It's not true.  It *would* be true, except...)

> I'm running on RHEL 7.8 and my git version is 1.8.3.1.

From the Git 1.8.5 release notes:

> ```
> * The "http.*" variables can now be specified for individual URLs.
>   For example,
>
>   [http]
>       sslVerify = true
>   [http "https://weak.example.com/"]
>       sslVerify = false
>
>   would flip http.sslVerify off only when talking to that specific
>   site.
> ```

Note that 1.8.5 > 1.8.3.1: your Git version is simply too old.